# Gdal_sieve does not run

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am working on a project to detect clearcut logging. i'm using the the methodology proposed by IRSTEA in 2015. 
To filter NDVI images calculated from sentinel 2 images, I'm using the QGIS command (Raster > Analysis > Sieve) on binary images. My problems it that it does not run at all with an error message "the process planted some time after being launched". 
Qgis 2.14.3

Any ideas why?

Comment: can you write the line you ran?

Comment: I just use the Qgis application (Raster > Analysis > Sieve), but it does not work

Comment: when you run it, below in the GUI there's the command, it says something like "gdal_sieve.py -st ..."